# Frequency analysis of multiple sawtooth signal

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft

Is there a way of calculating the fundamental frequency of a signal composed of multiple sawtooth functions?  I have a signal essential made of x number of noisy sawtooths and I want to get the amplitude and frequency of them.  See python code below:

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = signal.sawtooth(1 * np.pi * t) + 0.1*signal.sawtooth(4 * np.pi * t) + 0.01*signal.sawtooth(50 * np.pi * t)

plt.plot(t, y)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the plot
[sawtooth function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDcFU.png)

Is there a way to decompose the signal to get something like:

```
Frequency Amplitude
 1 1
 4 0.1
 50 0.01
```

I've tried using FFTs but the signal doesn't correspond well to the info above.  Any thoughts on a way to decompose a signal to its fundamental parts if it is not a sine/cose wave?

Answer (score 1):

if I correctly understood your query, you may use the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal
import scipy.fftpack

# Number of samplepoints : use 2**n powers to optimize FFT
N = 4096    # be aware of Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem
# Length of your signal
t_f = 20
# sample spacing
T = t_f / N
# Time signal vector
t = np.linspace(0, t_f, N)
#
# first with trigonometric functions to make sure it's working
y = 2*np.cos(t) + 12*np.cos(9*t) + 5*np.cos(42*t) # here you got 1-9-42 harmonics
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y) # use FFT algorithm on the temporal signal
xf = np.linspace(0.0, t_f/(2.0*T), N/2)  # taking advantage of symmetry of FFT if the signal is real valued
# Plot of the spectral output
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2]))
plt.show()
```

which gives with your functions :

```
# now with saw tooth functions
y = signal.sawtooth(1 * np.pi * t) + 0.1*signal.sawtooth(4 * np.pi * t) + 0.01*signal.sawtooth(50 * np.pi * t)
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, t_f/(2.0*T), N/2)
# Plot of the spectral output
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2]))
plt.show()
```

After that, you may be able to post process these results and obtain the given Frequency/Amplitude of the spectral components of your signal.

Hope this may help you. Regards.

Comment: The problem is the sawtooth signal has a decaying DFT signature that needs to be removed. I almost need to divide/subtract the FFT of the signal by an FFT of a clean signal but I haven't figured out the way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of periods of all the sawtooth waves is large enough, try using autocorrelation instead of an FFT.